# sqlcmd with jQuery in the insert statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd

I need to do some seeding of an MSSQL database and I have many sql files that need to run in order.

Basically I have a start.sql file...

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

PRINT 'First File'
:r "c:\sql\firstfile.sql"

PRINT 'Second File'
:r "c:\sql\secondfile.sql"
```

And I am running this with `sqlcmd -S LOCALHOST\SqlExpress -E -i "C:\sql\start.sql" -x`

The issue is in one of the files I am inserting HTML data into the DB and it has some script references in it that have jQuery `$('#stuff')` in them. This is throwing syntax errors because of the SQL variable substitution.

I was hoping the `-x` option would stop the substitution, but I still got an error. Am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Command Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) is supposed to treat `$(something)` as a [variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx).

When in SQLCMD Mode, the result of `PRINT '$test'` will be `$test`, but executing `PRINT '$(test)'` will return the message `'test' scripting variable not defined.` Using the -x option (**lowercase** x) should NOT return that message, though.

I tested that out by running the following in a Windows command prompt:

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -E -i "c:\failsInSqlCmdMode.sql" -x
```

Where the .sql script contains the following SQL:

```
declare @test varchar(10) 
set @test = '$(#stuff)'
select @test
go
```

The result is:

```
----------
$(#stuff)

(1 rows affected)
```

Only when I remove the -x from the end of the command, I get an error:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Syntax error at line 2 near command '#' in file 'C:\failsInSqlCmdMode.sql'.

I tested this out on Windows 7 x64 connecting to SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Did you try one where the `c:\failsInSqlCmdMode.sql` actually calls other .sql files with `:r c:\another\file.sql`. Because that's my issue.

Comment: I switched up my approach and just made a bat file that does a sqlcmd for every one of the files I need to make sure that the `'x` get's applied. And that seems to work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I was getting all kinds of odd syntax errors from a backup script I generated via SSMS. Turns out some of the columns had HTML content with variable-like syntax. Using the `-x` flag worked perfectly for me.